# Why does my code keep returning none instead of the barcode?

Tags: python

This code is supposed to print out a "barcode" from a given zip code. The problem is that it is only printing out **none** after it is done. No visible errors to me. Could you take a look?

```
def printDigit(d , x):
    if x <= 5:
        if d[x] == 0:
            return "||:::" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 1:
            return ":::||" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 2:
            return "::|:|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 3:
            return "::||:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 4:
            return ":|::|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 5:
            return ":|:|:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 6:
            return ":||:|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 7:
            return "|:::|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 8:
            return "|::|:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif d[x] == 9:
            return "|:|::" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
    else:
        return

zipCode = str(input("Input a zip code: "))
print(printDigit(zipCode , 0))
```

Comment: Your input is a string and you're comparing each character in it to an int.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Just print out the input with those lines? Can you give an example of what you want to print out please.

Comment: When you run this code you send to printDigit 2 variables, the zipcode and a number 0. The first thing you do in the function is check if 0<5, this is always true so we return nothing. Then we print it.

Comment: So the code should take a 5 digit zip code and print out the "barcode" version of it, which is just where every number in the zip code corresponds to a set of lines and colons. If I put in 95014 for example, it should return ||:|:::|:|:||::::::||:|::|:::|||.

Comment: The comment by @birryree is really all you need here. There are other ways you could improve things, but if you just change it to compare the digit characters to digits characters instead of numbers, your code will work, and if you understand it, that's good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do this. Instead of using recursion for this problem you can just iterate through the characters of the input. If there are less than 5 characters you can immediately `return None` since the zip code input is wrong. Then we will iterate through each character and add the barcode to a list.

At the end we check if the length of the list is 25, this would mean that we indeed had 5 numbers, if there are any letters or special characters they will get ignored.

```
def printDigit(d):
    if len(str(d)) == 5 and str(d).isdigit():
        temp = []
        for i in str(d):
            if i == '0':   temp.extend("||:::")
            elif i == '1': temp.extend(":::||")
            elif i == '2': temp.extend("::|:|")
            elif i == '3': temp.extend("::||:")
            elif i == '4': temp.extend(":|::|")
            elif i == '5': temp.extend(":|:|:")
            elif i == '6': temp.extend(":||:|")
            elif i == '7': temp.extend("|:::|")
            elif i == '8': temp.extend("|::|:")
            elif i == '9': temp.extend("|:|::")
        return ''.join(temp)
    else: return None

zipCode = str(input("Input a zip code: "))
print(printDigit(zipCode))
```

---

To avoid rewriting code segments. We can also use a dictionary to hold the translation of each digit to its barcode value. Then we can use list comprehensions as

```
def printDigit(d):
    dic = {'0': "||:::", '1': "||:::", '2': "::|:|",
           '3': "::||:", '4': ":|::|", '5': ":|:|:",
           '6': ":||:|", '7': "|:::|", '8': "|::|:",
           '9': "|:|::"}
    if len(str(d)) == 5 and str(d).isdigit():
        return ''.join([dic[i] for i in str(d)])
    else: return None

zipCode = str(input("Input a zip code: "))
print(printDigit(zipCode))
```

Comment: Wow that's incredible. It's a little too complicated for me to understand, though. What does the temp.extend do? The code works exactly like I need it to.

Comment: `temp=[]` initializes an empty list. The extend function will put each individual character into the list as its own element. For example, `temp.extend('1234')` would give "['1', '2', '3', '4']". For your case you could also use `temp.append()`. It would work too. For example `temp.append('1234')` gives "['1234']", then we can append again `temp.append('5678')` which then results as "['1234', '5678']".

Comment: @PotatoToddler `tmp.extend(x)` is exactly the same thing as `temp += list(x)`. I'm not actually sure why this code is using `extend` instead of `append`, but whether `tmp` ends up as 25 single-character strings or 5 5-character strings, the `join` will give the same result at the end.

Comment: @PotatoToddler Also, if you don't understand some code, try adding some temporary `print` calls. For example, each time through the loop `pint(temp)` and you should understand what it's doing.

Comment: Oh that's super cool and useful. Thanks for both the solution and lesson on temps haha!

Comment: `temp` is just a variable name.. You can write any legal name there. Just replace your name instead of `temp` everywhere it'll still work. The variable name is just a symbolic name for the value contained at a specific address in your memory. The name is arbitrary.

Comment: @abarnert chose to use `.extend()` because it seemed to be slightly faster than `.append()`. In this case it's small scale so its irrelevant I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You're accepting the entered zipCode as a String object. So while comparing it's elements you can either put the digits within single quotes or convert the zipCode to an integer. I'd also suggest checking if the current character in the string is a digit using the isdigit() method. Also when the value of x crosses 5 then your printDigit method returns NoneType which cannot be combined with a string object. Therefore return ""

```
def printDigit(d , x):
    if x <len(d) and d[x].isdigit():
        if int(d[x]) ==0:
            return "||:::" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 1:
            return ":::||" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 2:
            return "::|:|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 3:
            return "::||:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 4:
            return ":|::|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 5:
            return ":|:|:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)

        elif int(d[x]) == 6:
            return ":||:|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 7:
            return "|:::|" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 8:
            return "|::|:" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
        elif int(d[x]) == 9:
            return "|:|::" + printDigit(d , x + 1)
    else:
        return ""

zipCode = input("Input a zip code: ")
print(printDigit(zipCode , 0))
```